# Comparison Express JS, Angular JS vs Backbone JS

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, express, requirements

I am starting to learn node js for a while and it seem amazing. 
When I start to apply nodejs to build a scalable website, I am wondering to do Express for back-end, BackBone Js or Angular JS for front-end, people said Express JS is very fast, while Backbone.js seem to be MVC,

so 
1) can we have a comparison between the Backbone and Angular
2) under which project requirements, developer skills,... we should select either framework ?
3) And which one can integrate better with Express ? 
I am a newbie to nodejs so all suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is for backend servers. So it can be compared to other languages' frameworks such as Sinatra (Ruby), Django (Python), etc.

Backbone is a minimalist frontend framework, comparable to others in the game such as Ember.js, Angular, etc.

The main difference is that Express runs on a server and Backbone in a browser. Express is for making APIs and Backbone for client apps.

Comment: thank MT, I got the differences now, what is your idea about angular vs Backbone ?

Comment: That is of course highly subjective - you and I might not want the same things and apps might need different things that one might do better than others. I am personally not a huge Backbone guy.

This article is quite old but might set you in the right direction: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/